# "Ela casou em 1998" ou "Ela se casou em 1998"?

Tags: verbos, regência-verbal, verbos-intransitivos, verbos-transitivos

De acordo com o [**Priberam**](https://dicionario.priberam.org/casar), o verbo *casar* pode ser usado como verbo transitivo, verbo intransitivo, ou verbo pronominal.

1. Eles casaram em 1998. (verbo intransitivo)
2. Vou cobrir a aposta e casar mais dois mil reais. (verbo transitivo direto)
3. Você não soube que ela casou com Pedro?  (verbo transitivo indireto)
4. Eles se casaram na Notre Dame. (verbo pronominal)

Os exemplos acima são de minha autoria, portanto, corrijam-me se eu estiver errado.

Minha pergunta: eu sempre ouvi, no pt-BR falado, duas formas para a mesma ação, como:

- Ela **casou** há cerca de um ano.
- Ela **se casou** há cerca de um ano.
- Eles **casaram** só no civil.
- Eles **se casaram** só no civil.
- Ela **casou** com ele por dinheiro.
- Ela **se casou** com ele por dinheiro.

**Estariam as duas formas corretas?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No sentido de *unir-se em casamento*, pode de facto usar-se tanto a forma intransitiva como pronominal:

> Quando *casara* estava eu na Europa (M. Assis)
>   Do filho que *casar-se* não queria. (Camões).

No sentido de *unir por casamento*, *promover o casamento de*, é verbo transitivo:

> Chamou-o a rainha, deu-lhe um dote e ordenou ao capelão que os *casasse*.  (Camilo)
>   Rapariga, eu à força não te *caso*. Vais ver o homem. Se gostares, bem; se não gostares, nada perdido. (Camilo)

Para cada uma destas variantes também podemos acrescentar um complemento oblíquo com *com*, ou por vezes *ao*:

> Pediu ao vigário de Santa Marinha que o *casasse* *com* Josefa. (Camilo)
>   *Casou* em 1859 *com* esta Natividade, que ia então nos vinte anos. (M. Assis)
>   Um moço estouvado… pretendia, há três meses, *casar-se com* a filha dele. (M. Barreto)

A fonte e os exemplo são do *Dicionário de Verbos e Regimes* de Francisco Fernandes (45.ª ed.)

Comment: Algum exemplo para "casar ao" ?

Answer (score 0):

De acordo com meu conhecimento como nativo, falante e estudante da língua as duas formas estão corretas pois o verbo casar permite as duas construções.

Resposta baseada na gramática Bechara.

Links que podem ser úteis para esclarecer sua dúvida/problema:

- https://mariaelisaporchat.com/2010/10/29/casou-ou-se-casou/
- http://www.linguabrasil.com.br/img/colunas/Coluna_N295_2011-10-19.pdf
- http://www.portalentretextos.com.br/materia/casar-sentar-mudar-divociar-verbos-pronominais,6985

Comment: Waghley, bem-vindo à comunidade. Eu tenho uma sugestão: a tua resposta ficaria muito mais sólida se incluíres uma citação da parte relevante da gramática do Bechara (e título da obra, ano e página). As respostas e perguntas aqui neste site não incluem saudações; então eu tirei as tuas. Nós não somos rígidos ou solenes; uma resposta pode ter um toque de humor, mas deve ser como um artigo, não uma mensagem pessoal. Já nos comentários, o conteúdo é mais livre. Então, abraço, e força aí.